# Can I hone Silestone from a glossy finish to a matte finish?

Tags: kitchen-counters, sanding

I would like to hone (make the glossy finish matte) my Silestone kitchen countertops.  Is this possible either through an acid wash, sanding or other?  Sanding works on samples but will be difficult to get uniformity on that large a surface.

Answer (score 1):

Silestone is made of quartz (mohs scale of around 7 if I remeber correctly). Try wetsanding with > 1000 grit so that you don't get scratches in the surface.

Comment: when using the method you give above or any (other) appropriate method to achieve the look (result) "Mark" is after, should you be concerned about making the surface more susceptible to damage (eg staining)? Or is it considered a non-issue? Am asking, as it is my understanding that a matte finish is achieved by opening up the pours a little.

Comment: Quartz is a crystalline form of glass, so I would expect it to stain about as much as scuffed up glass. The only problem I would expect would be with the polyester binders that the use. As with anything else, test in an inconspicuous area first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can hone something to a lesser polish as the term refers to smoothing a surface--which is the opposite of what you are looking to do.

Sandblasting is typically the way to knock back the gloss on a surface. Not sure how practical that would be inside a kitchen, though.